# Set Values of Embedded Schema

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I am trying to inject data into the correct fields when making a component. So far I am able to inject data into Text fields, Number fields, Date fields, Multi-value fields. I use this function to do this.

```
Utilities.PushValuesToField = function PushValuesToField(fieldId, values) {
    var p = this.properties;
    var item = $display.getItem();
    if (item) {
        if (item.getItemType() == "tcm:16") {
            var fieldBuilder = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder;
            if (fieldBuilder.getField(fieldId)) {
                var field = fieldBuilder.getField(fieldId);
                var countOfValues = values.length;
                if (countOfValues > 0) {
                    field.setValues([values[0]]);
                    try{
                        for (var iValue = 1 ; iValue < countOfValues ; iValue++) {
                            var addedField = fieldBuilder.properties.input.insertField(field);
                            addedField.setValues([values[iValue]]);
                            field = addedField;
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        return 100;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now I would like to be able to do the same but then for Embedded schemas. So making a function where I can give an id and a value and put that value in the correct field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
EmbeddedSchemaFieldObject.getField("Name of child field");
```

So The function that I made to do this:

```
Utilities.PushValuesToEmbeddedField = function PushValuesToEmbeddedField(EmbeddedFieldId, fieldId, values) {
    var p = this.properties;
    var item = $display.getItem();
    if (item) {
        if (item.getItemType() == "tcm:16") {
            var fieldBuilder = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder;
            if (fieldBuilder.getField(EmbeddedFieldId)) {
                var field = fieldBuilder.getField(EmbeddedFieldId);
                if (field.getField(fieldId)) {
                    var childField = field.getField(fieldId);
                    var countOfValues = values.length;
                    if (countOfValues > 0) {
                        childField.setValues([values[0]]);
                        try {
                            for (var iValue = 1 ; iValue < countOfValues ; iValue++) {
                                var addedField = fieldBuilder.properties.input.insertField(childField);
                                addedField.setValues([values[iValue]]);
                                childField = addedField;
                            }
                        } catch (err) {
                            return 100;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Great that you could find it. Did you know you could do this with an Event as well, using TOM.NET/server side code?

Comment: Yes but we were instructed to do as much as possible without the use of TOM.NET so I was determined to try and solve it this way.